# How to return from Glide onResourceReady

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm trying to return string `s[0]` after Glide `onResourceReady`, but return statement is executing before `onResourceReady` method, so now I want to return a string from Glide `onResourceReady` but it's not working.

How to make `onResourceReady` to return String?

Please help me.

```
private String storeToLocalDisk(String urlS, final int id) {

    final String[] s = new String[1];

    Glide.with(getContext()).asBitmap().load(urlS).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            s[0] = saveToInternalStorage(resource,id);
            return s[0]; // not working
        }
    });
   // return s[0];
}
```

Comment: It's Async method you cannot get expected output while returning value, Instead of returning it you just use new method and pass the value that you need

Answer (score 1):

This `return s[0];` won't because 1st `return s[0];` this will execute then you will get data from `Glide` .

I will  suggest use `LiveData` just like this :

```
 //Create livedata variable 
 MutableLiveData<String> liveData;

 //then initialize this variable in oncreate or where you want just like this
 liveData= new MutableLiveData<>();

 //then set value to LiveData just like this
 liveData.setValue("set you value");

 //then Create observer for livedata. whenever data change in Livedata  onChanged method will call 
  Observer<String> observer= new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
       Log.e("dataChange",s);
    }
};
```

set this `observer` to `livedata` just like this

```
  liveData.observe(this,observer):
```

Now at last `setvalue` of `livedata` just like this

```
liveData.setValue("set you value");
```

I had almost same issue this thing works for me.

Comment: I set livedata value to  liveData.setValue(s[0]);  and created observer in oncreate method but onChanged method is not called.

Comment: sorry i forgot to show one step .I'm updating answer.

Comment: then upvote and accept the answer and help other :)